# How to set model.changed for an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For any ActiveRecord model, I can access the *changed* attribute to get an array of fields that were changed.

For instance:

```
a = Article.find(1)
a.title = "New Title"
a.changed => returns ["title"]
```

Is there a way for me to set the "changed" attribute myself? Suppose I want to make it empty. Reason being, I'm actually reading the article attributes from a cache (Redis, but it doesn't matter which), instead of from the database.

Unfortunately, I can't do

```
def getArticleFromCache
    json = getJsonFromCache()
    a = Article.new
    a.attributes = json
    a.changed = [] #doesn't work, changed contains ALL the attributes in the json
    return a
end
```

What can I do?

In other words, I want someone who's calling *getArticleFromCache* to appear as if it's getting it from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that you basically want to clean the changed history.

For Rails 3, so you could use `a.instance_variable_set(:@changed_attributes, {})`

For Rails 4, you can just use `a.clear_changes_information`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via private methods from [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

For rails 4 it is:

```
a.send(:clear_changes_information)
```

For rails 3 it is:

```
a.send(:reset_changes)
```

Obviously the methods being private gives a pretty big hint that they aren't designed to be called directly but it will work.

You may have more success, or a neater solution, by wrapping your `Article` in another class to decorate it. You could then override `changes` in that decorator class to indicate that there are no changes. You'll have to decide how much an article from the cache actually needs to behave like a model class. Do you want to save it, for example; you might end up with more problems than just trying to hide the changes.